# Reactjs callback get error before error is returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, callback

Hi I'm a beginner in react and I have the following code

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';

import { useCartContext } from '@magento/peregrine/lib/context/cart';


export const useWishlistAllItems = props => {
    const { items,mutations } = props;
    const { addSimpleWishListItemToCartMutation } = mutations;

    const [{ cartId }] = useCartContext();
 

    const [addWishlistItemToCart, { error, loading }] = useMutation(addSimpleWishListItemToCartMutation);


    const handleAddAllItemsToCart = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            items.map((item,index) => {
                if (item.product.__typename !== 'ConfigurableProduct'){
                    const cartItem = {
                        data: {
                            quantity: 1,
                            sku: item.product.sku
                        }
                    };
                    addWishlistItemToCart({
                        variables: {
                            cartId,
                            cartItem
                        }
                    });
                }
            })

        } catch {
            return;
        }
    }, [addWishlistItemToCart, cartId, items]);

    const saveWishList = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            window.location.reload(false);
        }catch {
            return;
        }
    }, []);



    return {
        handleAddAllItemsToCart,
        saveWishList,
        hasError: !!error,
        isLoading: loading
    };
};
```

The problem is that the error is displayed before the error is returned to my main component.I get the following
[image: error]

I have handled the returned error in my component properly but the problem is I get the error as above before returned to the component.I think It is because of the callback function.Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Running async method without await is like just starting Task without
> monitoring it's progress and results.
> So, once again check your code using await and return the appropriate output.

Comment: where should i use await.I used it at the start of items.map((item,index) =>  but get the same result